# Any way to implement ads to Kivy App?

Tags: kivy

Can anyone help me with any sdk for implementing ads in kivy app.
Revmobs have stopped supporting Kivy.
Any other method of implementing ads would also work.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have had success with **AdBuddiz** via **jnius**, I guess that you can use **any java SDK on android** this way:

```
PythonActivity=autoclass("org.renpy.android.PythonActivity")
AdBuddiz=autoclass("com.purplebrain.adbuddiz.sdk.AdBuddiz")

AD_CHANCE = 0.06

def init():
    AdBuddiz.setPublisherKey("YOUR SECRET KEY .... ")
    #delete this before going to play at the store...
    AdBuddiz.setTestModeActive()
    AdBuddiz.cacheAds(PythonActivity.mActivity)

def show():
    if (random.random() < AD_CHANCE):
        log.info("Showing Ad!!!")
        try:
            AdBuddiz.showAd(PythonActivity.mActivity)
        except Exception:
            log.exception("Pizza is not healthy...")
    else:
        log.warn("Skipping the AD this time ;)")
```

I guess that on **iOS** you can use **PyObjC** to achieve the same results...

Comment: `#delete this before going to play at the store...` obviously, storing it in a pure string is kind of.... crazy, but then again, does the `AdBuddiz` package check for some other variable, or how does it know who does the ad belong to?

Comment: The comment goes to the TestMode line below. Your secret key should stay, AdBuddiz uses your SecertKey to know who are you ...

Comment: Is there a full guide, like which sdk i need to install, what changes in buildozer etc

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/AdBuddiz-Android-advertisements-integration-for-Kivy-apps